# How to monitor ospf session using check_ospf plugin in icinga2

Tags: linux

I have tried to use check_ospf plugin downloaded from nagios to help me in monitoring the ospf sessions between two host running quagga. I have tested the check_snmp plugin on the hosts, and they are working fine, however, the check_ospf plugin is not working. When i use this command

## ./check_ospf -H  -C public

it gives an output of 
PACKET ERROR: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Please i need help on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an ip host address after `-H` and `-C` is the community so you will need to add your community just after the `-C`.

If you are using cisco or other equipment please download the MIB and save it onto the server under `/usr/share/mibs`